# How to do an extension of BonitaBPM?

Tags: bonita

I have been working for a while on a project about the extension of some functionalities in BonitaBPM (especially control access ones) but I still don't know how to start, so I want to know:

1. what are the pre-requirements to do such a project (languages...)?
2. How can I get the source code of bonita (I have seen in the official website that I should download it from github but I found a lot of versions)
3. Finally, what are the steps that I am supposed to take?

Comment: Hi, could you be more precise about your project. What is it exactly that you want to want to achieve? Change the authentication mechanism to use an external system and if yes which one? Change the authorization mechanism and if yes for what actions?

Answer (score 0):

Note that REST API already provides an extensible control access solution. You can refer to the [REST API authorization](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/rest-api-authorization-1) to get all the details.

If you have other extension requirements, knowledges needed will depend on the kind of components you are trying to tune:

- Bonita BPM Studio is Eclipse based so knowledges in Eclipse plugin development as well as framework used will be required.
- Bonita BPM Engine is developed in Java with important use of library such as Hibernate, Quartz... but also Java EE services such as JTA.
- Bonita BPM Portal is a Java EE web application that make use of web framework such as GWT, JQuery and AngularJS...

On the documentation page about building the solution you can find the list of git repositories you need to clone in order to built all components.

Comment: Thank you Antoine , but I still don't understand .How does this API work ? and can I use my own database with it ?

Comment: To clarify your question can you provide a little bit more about your use case and what you are trying to achieve? API is a solution for forms/pages and external application to interact with Bonita BPM Engine. Bonita provide a configuration solution to secure access to those API.